# How to test instance variables in an ActionMailer object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, actionmailer, instance-variables

There is a `before_action` callback method in my ActionMailer object which is responsible for setting some instance variables.

```
class TestMailer < ApplicationMailer
   before_action :set_params

   def send_test_mail
     mail(to: @email, subject: subject)
   end

   def set_params
     @account = account.email 
     @date = some_action(account.updated_at)
   end
end
```

The question is How one can test these variables in a rspec test?
some thing like:

```
describe TestMailer do 
 describe '#set_params' do
   described_class.with(account: account, subject: subject).send_test_mail.deliver_now
   expect(@date).to eq(Date.today)
 end
end
```

any clue would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could setup a `spy` inside a mock method `instance_variable_set`, then validate that spy

```rb
class TestMailer < ApplicationMailer
 attr_accessor :day
 # ...
end

describe TestMailer do 
 let(:freeze_today) { Time.now.utc }

 it '#set_params' do 
  # freeze today
  allow_any_instance_of(TestMailer).to receive(:some_action)
  .with(account.updated_at)
  .and_return(freeze_today)

  # spy
  @spy = nil
  allow_any_instance_of(TestMailer).to receive(:day=) do |time|
   @spy = time
  end

  described_class.with(account: account, subject: subject)
  .send_test_mail
  .deliver_now

  expect(@spy).to eq(freeze_today)

  # or just simple like this  
  expect_any_instance_of(TestMailer).to receive(:day=).with(freeze_today)
 end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but Unfortunately `described_class.instance_variable_get(:@date)` returns `nil`. it seems that it is not working with ActionMailer.
I've also tried 
`expect(assigns(:@date)).to....`
But not working.

Comment: @FaridAnooshehpour, i quite remember that we use `assigns` in controller test cases, BTW, i updated my answer.

Comment: not sure `...to receive(:@date=)` to be a correct structure!! raises errors

Comment: @FaridAnooshehpour update: `day=` and also set `attr_accessor :day`

Comment: Thanks @lamPhan, I made it using `spy`

Answer (score 3):

I think that instead of testing the instance variables, it would be better to test the email body, for example:

```
expect(mail.body.encoded).to include(account.updated_at)
```

Comment: this is better way. p/s: you should stub `some_action` to return a fake time instead of `account.updated_at`.